# I need a dataset in which different facilities are situated on the roadnetwork?

Tags: data-request

I am working on a project of partitioning the road network for improving recommendation system . In this project I have to recommend nearest facilities such as restaurant , hotels, movie theaters etc based on road network distance . So I need a dataset for such activity . Can you suggest me some database . I am looking data any small city of Canada like calgary etc .

Comment: Have you tried openstreetmap.org ?

Comment: Does it provide the dataset together with the  facilities like restaurant , cinema halls , etc ?

Comment: It should provide a list of businesses, if that's what you mean? Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap has what you want, I think.